# SGE low priority single core jobs preventing multicore jobs

Tags: linux, multithreading, hpc, job-scheduling, sungridengine

I'm running SGE (6.2u5p2) on our beowulf cluster. I've got a couple of users who submit 10s of thousands of short (<15minute) jobs that are a low priority (i.e. they've set the jobs low priority so anyone can jump ahead of them). This works really well for other users running single core jobs, however anyone wishing to run something with multiple threads aren't able to. The single core jobs keep skipping ahead, never allowing (say 6 cores) to be available.

I don't really want to separate the users into two queues (i.e. single and multicore) since those using the multicore jobs use it briefly and then there are multiple cores left unused.

Is there a way in SGE to allow multi core jobs to reserve slots?

Many thanks,

Rudiga

Comment: Yes, research the topic of *advanced reservations* in the grid engine documentation.  But I don't immediately see the problem you (think you) have with separate queues, surely you can configure matters such that resources available to the multicore queue are available to the single core queue when the former is empty ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As "High Performance Mark" eludes to, using the -R option may help. See:

http://www.ace-net.ca/wiki/Scheduling_Policies_and_Mechanics#Reservation